# Loading another QGIS processing algorithm window from processing algorithm

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-processing

QGIS `Processing` class has a method `execAlgorithmDialog()` that opens the dialogue window of any processing algorithm.

I am writing a Plugin that has a processing algorithm `Run Analysis`, I also need to include another tool `Load Analysis` in my plugin suite, that takes a JSON file, which will consist of input parameters for `Run Analysis`, and using these parameters load the window of `Run Analysis`. I have been able to achieve this by using `execAlgorithmDialog()` and `postProcessAlgorithm()` but with one caveat, the `Load Analysis` window continues to run in the background until I close the newly popped up `Run Analysis` window. This is something I want to avoid. I am looking for a way to open new window and close the previous one at the same time.

Here is how my code looks like

```py
from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import QCoreApplication
from qgis.core import (QgsProcessingAlgorithm, QgsProcessingParameterFile)
from qgis import processing

class LoadAnalysis(QgsProcessingAlgorithm):
    load_parameters = {}

    def createInstance(self):
        return LoadAnalysis()

    def initAlgorithm(self, config=None):
        self.addParameter(QgsProcessingParameterFile('Previousrunfile', 'Previous run file', behavior=QgsProcessingParameterFile.File, fileFilter='JSON Files (*.json)', defaultValue=None))


    def processAlgorithm(self, parameters, context, feedback):
        # load json file dict into python object
        # and save it in self.load_parameters
        return {}


    def postProcessAlgorithm(self, context, feedback):
        processing.execAlgorithmDialog("native:dropgeometries", self.load_parameters)
        return {}
```

In this screenshot, I have replicated the behaviour using Drop Geometries algorithm inplace of `Run Analysis`. You can see that `Load Analysis` is running in the background.

[image]

Comment: Is this a problem?

Comment: Yes it is. I want it to terminate after making that call.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely this is because `feedback` instance is terminated after `postProcessAlgorithm` method.  The progress bar shows a busy indicator instead of a percentage of steps, since the first window does not know how long the second process opened by `execAlgorithmDialog` will take.

Comment: I understand. Is there a way to avoid this, is there another way to make `execAlgorithmDialog` call and terminate the previous window? Can threads be used to achieve this?

Comment: I have no idea for now.